# Why my function that uses if-statement doesn't execute itself correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

I am trying to create a table with a button in each row and when the button is clicked new row is created between the current and subsequent row. If any other button is pressed, previously created row is deleted and a new one is created on a new proper location. And so on, and so on. My approach is to use if-statement that would check if whichever button was pressed for the first time, if so, create a row on the proper location and save it's a position to currPos. On the second and each subsequent click, first thing is to delete the previously created row and create new in the proper location and save newly created row position to currPos(in order to third click and each subsequent would know which one to delete).

The problem is that 'if (first==true)' is never executed, that's why error demands to declare currPos at the beginning of the script, so I created it with value = -1, so when whichever button is pressed the last row is deleted, and the whole code is working as I want.

How can I fix my if-statement in order not to declare currPos at the beginning of the script, so that it's declaring in 'if(first==true)'?

/*
Additional
variable $firstPHP is created to connect onclick and specialFunc that there are two parameters, but the in PHP it's not even used - it knows that has to have two parameters because JS will use it(create it's own actually) later.
Is that good approach? Can I inform onclick button that JS needs the only rowID from PHP and the second parameter is created within JS function?
*/

```
<?php
$firstPHP = true;
$provider = "Test_provider";
echo '<table id="my-table">';
for($counter = 0; $counter <= 5; $counter++){
    $rowID=$counter+1;
    echo' <tr id ="'.$counter.'"><td><button onclick="specialFunc('.$firstPHP.',\''.$rowID.'\')">'.$provider.'</button></td><td>Row '.$counter.' Col '.$counter.'</td><td>Row '.$counter.' Col '.$counter.'</td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
<script>
var currPos= -1;
function specialFunc(first = true, test){   
    if (first == true){
        function addRow(test) {  
            var currPos = test;
            let tableRef = document.getElementById("my-table");
            let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(test);
            let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
            newCell.colSpan = 5;
            let newText = document.createTextNode('New bottom row1');
            newCell.appendChild(newText);
            first = false;
        }       
    }
        document.getElementById("my-table").deleteRow(currPos);
        let tableRef = document.getElementById("my-table");
        let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(test);
        let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        newCell.colSpan = 5;
        let newText = document.createTextNode('New bottom row2');
        newCell.appendChild(newText);
        currPos = test;

}
```

Problem solved using switch:

```
<?php
$provider = "Test_provider";
echo '<table id="my-table">';
for($counter = 0; $counter <= 10; $counter++){
    $rowID=$counter+1;
    echo' <tr id ="'.$counter.'"><td><button onclick="specialFunc('.$rowID.')">'.$provider.'</button></td><td>Row '.$counter.' Col '.$counter.'</td><td>Row '.$counter.' Col '.$counter.'</td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
<script>
isFirst = true;
console.log(isFirst);
function addRow(test) {  
            var currPos = test;
            let tableRef = document.getElementById("my-table");
            let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(test);
            let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
            newCell.colSpan = 5;
            let newText = document.createTextNode('TEXT INFO');
            newCell.appendChild(newText);
}
function specialFunc(test){ 
    switch(isFirst){
        case true:
        addRow(test);
        isFirst = false;
        currPos = test;
        break;
        case false:
        document.getElementById("my-table").deleteRow(currPos);
        addRow(test);
        currPos = test; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here; you are defining a function - that you never call - conditionally. So no, that code never gets executed.

Comment: _“Can I inform onclick button that JS needs only rowID from php and second parameter is created within JS function?”_ - why are you passing it as a parameter then in the first place? That makes rather little sense.

Comment: you should declare `function addRow()` outside `specialFunc()`and then wrap the rest of the code inside your condition `if (first==true) { ... }`

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: Here on streamable is what I'm trying to achieve(beside deleting last row on first click) and what is happenning on the second code. On pastebin is second version of code.
https://streamable.com/meyjz
https://pastebin.com/7hspY3Kd